# Ruby: Convert Constant to String

Tags: ruby

I'd like to convert the constant `FOO::BAR` to the string `"BAR"`.

This is the opposite of what [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize) does and is very similar to [`demodulize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-demodulize), except I expect a string instead of the actual Module reference.

I was thinking I could make my own helper to do this, but I'm not able to get the "stringified" version of `FOO::BAR`.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid any 3rd party gems.

Example:

```
class FOO
  BAR = {}
end

# this works
FOO            #=> FOO
FOO.name       #=> "FOO"    

# this doesn't
FOO::BAR       #=> {} 
FOO::BAR.name  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for {}:Hash
```

Comment: What you want to do doesn't make sense. Why do you want to get the "name" of a constant name? What is the use case for this?

Comment: The constant name is also a value for a service I'm implementing. It saves me from having to do `BAR = { name: 'BAR', other_field: other_value }`. If I can just use inflection to stringify the const name, I'm keeping DRY.

Comment: Your question is unclear: in your title, you say that you want the name of a module, in the first paragraph, you say you want the name of a module or class, but in your code sample, you actually have a hash (which obviously doesn't have a name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass constants, you can only pass objects. If you pass `FOO::BAR` to a method, you're not passing the constant, but the object that has been assigned to `FOO::BAR`, i.e. the hash.

In order to retrieve the constant's name an object has been assigned-to from the object itself, the object has to store the name somehow.

Modules do store the constant name they have been assigned-to (Ruby sets the name when a module is assigned to a constant for the first time). And because `FOO` is a module (classes are modules), you can call `FOO.name` and it returns `"FOO"`. But that only works because the object "knows" its name.

From the built-in objects, only `Module` (and therefore `Class`) has a [`name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-name) method that works this way.

You *could* add a `name` method to the hash instance `FOO::BAR` is referring to, although this is probably not what you want:

```
def (FOO::BAR).name
  'FOO::BAR'
end

FOO::BAR.name #=> "FOO::BAR"
```

Another way is to pass both, the constant (the object actually) and its module to a method:

```
def find_const(mod, obj)
  mod.constants.find { |c| mod.const_get(c).equal?(obj) }
end

find_const(FOO, FOO::BAR) #=> :BAR
```

The method traverses the module's constants and returns the (first) constant that refers to the passed object.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FOO
  class BAR           
  end
end

FOO::BAR.to_s.split('::').last
  #=> "BAR"
```

Note that the method [Module#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-to_s) "Returns a string representing this module or class. For basic classes and modules, this is the name". [Module#name](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-name) could be used in place of `to_s`.

Comment: This won't work as it would call `.to_s` on the const value and not the const name itself.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Don't you want a method that takes a nested class (e.g., `FOO::BAR`) as an argument and returns the innermost class as a string (here "BAR")? This does that.

Comment: I want to pass a reference to a class const `FOO::BAR` to a method which will convert and return the const name `BAR` to a string `"BAR"`. Your method returns the value of `FOO::BAR` and calls `.to_s` on the const value, not the const name itself.

Comment: I still don't understand your point, but I've added a bit that may clarify. This might also help: `VAL = 6; VAL.to_s #=> "6"`, whereas `FOO.to_s #=> "FOO"`. Both `VAL` and `FOO` are constants, but `FOO` is also a class name.

Comment: The problem is that `BAR` is not a class, it is a constant on `class Foo`. See how that changes your answer.

Comment: I really do appreciate the effort and I'm sorry that you don't understand. Stefan gets it and I will accept that answer.